# Better, shorter html, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 9 buttons which i made mouve hover pointer and divs clickable which opens next php files.
I have made them to lose pointer style after pressing and retrieve it after pressing other button and everything works fine.
But is there some way to make this code shorter and better?

It's code for single button

```
function Postac()
{
    document.getElementById("Okno_Gry").innerHTML='<object data = "Postac.php" width = "100%" height = "100%" ></object>';
    document.getElementById('PrzyciskPostac').removeAttribute("onclick"), 
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskPostac").style.cursor = "default";
        

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskWarsztat").setAttribute("onclick", "Warsztat()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskWarsztat").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskTargowisko").setAttribute("onclick", "Targowisko()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskTargowisko").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskArena").setAttribute("onclick", "Arena()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskArena").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskWyprawy").setAttribute("onclick", "Wyprawy()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskWyprawy").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskLochy").setAttribute("onclick", "Lochy()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskLochy").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskGildia").setAttribute("onclick", "Gildia()"), 
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskGildia").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskZamek").setAttribute("onclick", "Zamek()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskZamek").style.cursor = "pointer";

    document.getElementById("PrzyciskKopalnie").setAttribute("onclick", "Kopalnie()");
    document.getElementById("PrzyciskKopalnie").style.cursor = "pointer";

}
```

Comment: I'd look at adding an event handler to the parent element and using a single delegated event to handle all of it. Without seeing the HTML it isn't possible to show how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the click handler names in an array, then loop over it.

```
const click_handlers = ["Warsztat", "Targowisko", "Arena", ...];
click_handlers.forEach(name => {
    let el = document.getElementById(`Przycisk${name}`);
    el.setAttribute("onclick", `${name}()`);
    el.style.cursor = "pointer";
});
```

Comment: Missing a `{` in your arrow function

Comment: How it is supposed to remove attribute after pressing and add it back after pressing other button?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: I need button to be not clickable until other is pressed

Comment: You can set the button's `disabled` property.

Comment: Even if the `Button` is div box?

Comment: OK, so call `removeAttribute` from the functions like `Warsztat()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap repeated code:

```
document.getElementById("PrzyciskWarsztat").setAttribute("onclick", "Warsztat()");
document.getElementById("PrzyciskWarsztat").style.cursor = "pointer";
  ...   
document.getElementById("PrzyciskTargowisko").setAttribute("onclick", "Targowisko()");
document.getElementById("PrzyciskTargowisko").style.cursor = "pointer";
```

into function and then you can call it:

```js
function clickable(id, method) {
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("onclick", method);
  document.getElementById(id).style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

Code at the end become short:

```js
function Postac() {
  document.getElementById("Okno_Gry").innerHTML =
    '<object data = "Postac.php" width = "100%" height = "100%" ></object>';
  document.getElementById("PrzyciskPostac").removeAttribute("onclick"),
    (document.getElementById("PrzyciskPostac").style.cursor = "default");

  clickable("PrzyciskWarsztat", "Warsztat()");
  clickable("PrzyciskTargowisko", "Targowisko()");
  clickable("PrzyciskArena", "Arena()");
  clickable("PrzyciskWyprawy", "Wyprawy()");
  clickable("PrzyciskLochy", "Lochy()");
  clickable("PrzyciskGildia", "Gildia()"),
  clickable("PrzyciskZamek", "Zamek()");
  clickable("PrzyciskKopalnie", "Kopalnie()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use a loop to shorten this up.

Also I replaced your onlick attribute set with a call to element.addEventListener();

```
const elementsAndCallbacks = [
   { id: "PrzyciskWarsztat", callback: Warsztat },
   { id: "PrzyciskTargowisko", callback: Targowisko },
   //etc
]

elementsAndCallbacks.forEach(item => {
   const el = document.getElementById(item.id);
   el.addEventListener('click', item.callback);
   el.style.cursor = "pointer";
});
```